# Not getting to angularjs animation class breakpoint for removeClass or addClass

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, gsap

> My animation class is not triggering in this codepen. What am I missing? I get to the controller methods fine. I never make it inside the animation class, either addClass or removeClass?

[codepen angularjs animation link, same code as here](http://codepen.io/jstafford/pen/LNQEbx)

> This is my base animation that I am trying to incorporate into the animation class above.

[codepen base animation link, works fine, not the issue](http://codepen.io/jstafford/pen/repWeG)

The way this is setup, by clicking on each circle, you make it active. It initializes the active circle at the first one. This timeline will go to the empty circle with stroke when a banner slide is "active" and when not active, the timeline will go back to the solid fill with no stroke.

```js
angular.module("appBanner", [])
  .controller('bannerCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.slides = ["zero", "one", "two"];

    $scope.currentIndex = 0;
    $scope.currentSlideIndex = "zero";
    $scope.setCurrentSlideIndex = function(index) {
      $scope.currentIndex = index;
      $scope.currentSlideIndex = $scope.slides[$scope.currentIndex];
    }

    $scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function(slideIndex) {
      return $scope.currentSlideIndex === slideIndex;
    }
    
    
  })
  .animation('.navCircleTransition', function($window) {
    return {
      addClass: function(element, className, done) {
        if (className === 'active') {
          var svgEl = element.find("svg");
          navCircleAnimate(svgEl, "reverse");
        } else {
          done();
        }
      },
      removeClass: function(element, className, done) {
        var scope = element.scope();
        if (className === 'active') {
          var svgEl = element.find("svg");
          navCircleAnimate(svgEl, "reverse");
        } else {
          done();
        }
      }
    }
  });

function navCircleAnimate(el, direction) {
  var tlNavCircle = new TimelineMax({
    paused: true
  });
  tlNavCircle.set($(el), {
    drawSVG: "0% 100%",
    ease: Linear.easeInOut
  });
  tlNavCircle.to($(el), 1, {
    drawSVG: "0% 0%",
    fill: "none",
    ease: Linear.easeInOut
  });

  if (direction === "play") tlNavCircle.play();
  else tlNavCircle.reverse();
}
```

```css
.navCircleContainer {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px;
  bottom: 2.5px;
  left: 12.5%;
  width: 75%;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/DrawSVGPlugin.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="appBanner" ng-controller="bannerCtrl" class="navCircleContainer">
  <div id="autoNavCircle" class="navCircleTransition" ng-class="{active: isCurrentSlideIndex('auto')}" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex(0)">
    <svg id="circle" height="100" width="100">
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45"/>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div id="autoNavCircle" class="navCircleTransition" ng-class="{active: isCurrentSlideIndex('boatowners')}" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex(1)">
    <svg id="circle" height="100" width="100">
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45"/>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div id="autoNavCircle" class="navCircleTransition" ng-class="{active: isCurrentSlideIndex('commercial')}" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex(2)">
    <svg id="circle" height="100" width="100">
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to include ngAnimate in my module. grrr....